# Jquery Mobile Replace Page Dynamically Using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Hello Is it possible to use $(result_div).html(data).enhanceWithin();

Why Am I having an error `VM398:148 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).html(...).enhanceWithin is not a function`

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? Use .trigger('create') in 1.3.x (and below) instead of .enhanceWithin()

Comment: Thanks this solves the issue :)

Comment: glad it helped. Posted the same comment as answer. Please mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.trigger('create')` in 1.3.x (and below) instead of `.enhanceWithin()`